# Qliksense formulas in power bi dax

Tags: variables, powerbi, expression, dax, qliksense

first i am going to show what i have in qliksense

i create a varaible `VPEDate`.. in that i do this

```
=if(GetSelectedCount(PE_DATE)>0,Date(Max(GetFieldSelections(PE_DATE))),Date(max(PE_DATE)))
```

here `GetSelectedCount` and `GetFieldSelections` is function name not tables name

then i have another variable `Ear_Factor` in that i have formula is this

```
(
RangeMax(0,RangeMin(( POLICY_END_DATE-POLICY_EFFECTIVE_DATE+ 1),(Date(vPE_Date) - POLICY_EFFECTIVE_DATE +1)))
)
/
(POLICY_END_DATE-POLICY_EFFECTIVE_DATE+ 1)
```

then i have final  formula for `Premium_earned` which is like that

```
Sum(GROSS_PREMIUM * $(vEarnedFactor))
```

so how i recreate these formulas in power bi .. and create final formula ..

i have `PE_DATE` in Calendar table  in power bi ..

any idea please

Comment: It'll be much easier to help you if you describe your data model and what you want to achieve/expected outcome. Code from another system just makes things more difficult.

Comment: i just want to be rewrite these expressions in power bi .. @RADO